# Button [disabled]="NgForm.form.invalid" causes flicker disabled due to NgForm valid at ngOnInit then invalid once page loaded

Tags: angular

- I have a submit button for an NgForm, for which the [disabled] attribute of the button is bound to the "NgForm.form.invalid" property.
- When the form is invalid (NgForm.form.invalid = true), the submit button is disabled, this is the correct behaviour.
- However, in my large application the button is first visible as enabled, then changes to disabled.
- I think this is because at the start of the component lifecycle the form is considered valid, as can be seen from the below plunker ngOnInit and ngAfterContentInit events.

https://plnkr.co/edit/OJEoafoPZpz8gaxEbTBb?p=preview

**What approach should I take to ensure the button is initialised as disabled and then remains disabled until the form is valid? I need to avoid the temporary state at the beginning of the component lifecycle where the form is considered as valid... even though it isn't.**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>app.component</h1>

    <form #fruitForm="ngForm">
      <input [(ngModel)]="fruit" name="fruit" required type="text">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="fruitForm.form.invalid">Save</button>
    </form>

    <div>
      {{atNgOnInit}}
      <br>{{atNgAfterContentInit}}
      <br>currently... fruitForm.form.valid?: {{fruitForm.form.valid}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  public fruit = '';
  public atNgOnInit = '';
  public atNgAfterContentInit = '';

  @ViewChild('fruitForm') fruitForm: NgForm;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.atNgOnInit = `ngOnInit event... fruitForm.form.valid?: ${this.fruitForm.form.valid}`;
    // REPORTS FORM TO BE VALID.
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.atNgAfterContentInit = `ngAfterContentInit event... fruitForm.form.valid?: ${this.fruitForm.form.valid}`;
    // REPORTS FORM TO BE VALID.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed approach to use angular reactive forms instead of template forms... reactive forms seem a lot more controllable and the above problem has gone away.